# undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(...)'

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, cmake, linker-errors

I want to compile [doppia](https://bitbucket.org/rodrigob/doppia), which has OpenCV as a dependency. Currently I am using OpenCV 2.4.9.1, which is the default on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine besides the references to the function `imwrite`.

```
...

[100%] Linking CXX executable objects_detection

undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/objects_detection.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target 'objects_detection' failed
make[2]: *** [objects_detection] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/objects_detection.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/objects_detection.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The file that throws the error is `IntegralChannelsDetector.cpp`. 
In it, both `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp` and `opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp` are included.

Running `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` also returns that all modules are linked correctly.

Researching about my error I learnt that if I was using OpenCV 3.x I'd have to include the `img_codecs` module, but that is not the case for OpenCV 2.x. I fear I'm stuck on 2.x for compatibility reasons.

Is there something left I could try to get the linking process completed?

Comment: This is NOT an include problem, it is a linking problem. BTW, if you want you can also use the opencv.hpp header, which includes almost all the headers... this way you are sure you got it included. Now to your problem, the compilers finds the function and knows about it from the include, but it can not find the implementation that should come from the .cpp or from a lib (or .h/.hpp if it is templated). You should show how are you doing the compilation, maybe your CMake file is the one at fault, or maybe cmake does not find correctly opencv

Comment: thanks @api55! In the cmake I have not specified anything about opencv, but when I call cmake, doppia tells me `Checking for module 'opencv>=2.3' -- Found opencv, version 2.4.9.1`. Including the opencv lib directory by adding `set(opencv_LIBRARY_DIRS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")` in the cmake didn't make the error gone unfortunately. Neither did it help to add the `-lopencv_highgui` or `-lopencv_imgproc` flags to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Somehow cmake is currently able to find all other parts of opencv.

Comment: Just checked out the doppia source... the cmake files used there are horribly done :/ they use a bunch of static paths instead of letting CMake find it. In a normal CMake with opencv you would see something like "find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)" Which will find the installed version of opencv and set the cmake variables. Then you will see it using this variables everywhere else that is needed

Comment: I tried it out to add `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` to the file src/applications/objects_detection/CMakeLists.txt similar to how they do it with Boost. But it doesn't change the error.

Comment: I believe this explains the problem and solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276430/2836621